# How to find element by Key in React?

Tags: reactjs

```
<ul>
    <li key='search1'>1234</li>
    <li key='search2'>5678</li>
    <li key='search3'>9</li>
</ul>
```

How to find element by Key and change element values like addClass/innerHtml?

Note: In Plain React - No Flux or Jsx.

Comment: If you want to change a class or the content of an element, do not use `addClass` or `innerHtml` but make it work in the _React way_ by dynamically adding classes and children/content in the `render` method. Finding and changing the element is the _jQuery way_.

Comment: If you are looking for an equivalent of jQuery.find within react (per the comment below "I am trying to...find a list element"), I suggest you check out this site for the js equivalent of many jQuery methods: [youmightnotneedjquery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/). Regardless, I would also suggest you spend some time learning more about how react works-- @zwippie Is dead on in his comment above.

Comment: @zwippie: Thanks. Can you provide any link for Plain ReactJs Learning

Comment: The [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html) are a must read. For someone with a jQuery background, perhaps [this article](https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/react-components-from-a-jquery-programmer-background) might be helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Access to `key` has been removed in React.

> The props key and ref were already reserved property names. 
>   ...
>   You can no longer access this.props.ref and this.props.key from inside the Component instance itself.
>   https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/10/16/react-v0.12-rc1.html#breaking-change-key-and-ref-removed-from-this.props

You can simply use a different name (e.g. 'reactKey') and access it via props. Here is a demo: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/PGaxdx

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child key="testKey1" keyProp="testKey1"/>
        <Child key="testKey2" keyProp="testKey2"/>
        <Child key="testKey3" keyProp="testKey3"/>
        <Child key="testKey4" keyProp="testKey4"/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);  // only 'keyProp' is available

    let getClassName = () => {
      switch (this.props.keyProp) {
        case 'testKey1': 
          return 'red';
        case 'testKey2': 
          return 'green';
        case 'testKey3': 
          return 'blue';
        default: 
          return 'black';
       }
    };

    return (
      <div className={getClassName()}>
        Some Text
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: What I am trying to do is find a list element and add a class to that

Comment: I've just added more info along with an example. Is this what you are after?

Comment: Just added an example showing how you can modify an element: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/PGaxdx

Comment: I agree this workaround may solve my problem, but looking for find method in React Js.

Comment: this can't be possible. Several react experts I know expect there to be a way to access the key

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get access to the DOM node of a React element, use the `ref` prop.
**But** in most cases, you can achieve what you're looking for without using Refs, so make sure you are not abusing this feature.

Here is some information from React docs: [Refs and the DOM - React](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

**Refs and the DOM**

> Refs provide a way to access DOM nodes or React elements created in the render method.

**When to Use Refs**

> There are a few good use cases for refs:
>
> - Managing focus, text selection, or media playback.
> - Triggering imperative animations.
> - Integrating with third-party DOM libraries.
>
> Avoid using refs for anything that can be done declaratively.

**Creating Refs**

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} />;
  }
}
```

**Accessing Refs**

```
const node = this.myRef.current;
```

Comment: Instead of just linking to an external source please also include necessary quotes and code blocks in your answer. This to ensure your answer stays usable and valid, even if the linked website is down in the future.